# DNF missing config-manager command

Tags: linux, centos, spotify, centos7, yum

I am attempting to install `dnf` on my CENTOS 7 machine. Using [this as my guideline](https://www.vultr.com/docs/use-dnf-to-manage-software-packages-on-centos-7) I ran the first two commands of

`sudo yum install epel-release`

`sudo yum install dnf`

and that successfully works.

```
Installed:
dnf.noarch 0:0.6.4-2.el7
```

Now I am trying to install Spotify which according to [this site](http://negativo17.org/spotify-client/) I need to run

```
[joey ~]# dnf config-manager --add-repo=http://negativo17.org/repos/fedora-spotify.repo
No such command: config-manager. Please use /bin/dnf --help
It could be a DNF plugin command.
```

In the DNF site it looks like it goes to 2.0 so I am guessing I am using an outdated DNF but it looks like the latest for me is `0.6.4-2.el7`. So I go to the [DNF Github page](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/) to try to install it manually. I clone it and attempt to run the first command.

```
[joey dnf]$ sudo dnf builddep dnf.spec
No such command: builddep. Please use /bin/dnf --help
It could be a DNF plugin command.
```

I am not sure what else to do at this point. I am basically just trying to get Spotify installed on my CentOS machine and not sure how to proceed from here.

**Attempts/Update**

```
[joey ~]$ sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-config-manager
CentOS-7 - cr                                   7.3 MB/s | 5.0 MB     00:00    
Using metadata from Thu Dec  1 16:19:53 2016
No package dnf-plugin-config-manager available.
Error: no package matched: dnf-plugin-config-manager
```

Comment: Did you try installing the plugins for dnf?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just tried it now. Not sure if I did it correctly but I updated my original question.

Answer (score 59):

`sudo yum install dnf-plugins-core` did the trick for me.

UPDATE: on el7, el8, el9 there is a better way

- when you try to execute `dnf config-manager -h` it will tell you to try `dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'`

```
# centos7
# rocky8
# rocky9
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'
```

p.s. the high level solution is actually "try to execute the `dnf config-manager -h` and if the command fails then read the error message and try installing what the error message recommends".

Comment: this did not work for me: `No package dnf-plugins-core available.`

Answer (score 0):

Install the COPR plugin and EPEL

```
$ sudo yum install yum-plugin-copr epel-release
```

Enable this repo

```
$ sudo yum copr enable ngompa/snapcore-el7
```

Install snapd

```
$ sudo yum install snapd
```

Enable snapd.socket

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
```

Install GNOME Software snap plugin, note that GNOME Software gets replaced in this step

```
$ sudo yum install gnome-software-snap
```

#### How do I run spotify...

run 'spotify' in your terminal
Or search for the App in your applications

For more tips you can take a look at my Github repo: https://github.com/Winterhart/CentOS7-Setup